# Deploying to AKS

Tags: gitlab, azure-aks, private

I have a private gitlab repo and able to create the image for my containerized deployment using a pipeline. I can push the image to the K8S cluster in AKS. The outbound traffic from gitlab to internet is opened but inbound traffic is not allowed. I created a gitlab agent and installed into the K8S cluster. But the agent is not able to do connect to the private gitlab due to access restriction. Is there any way to complete the pipeline to deploy the image into the AKS cluster with this restriction?